# Gupshup whatsapp template message using sandbox?

Tags: gupshup

Can I send template messages to users who are not opt-in and not active using the sandbox app?

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox App on Gupshup works in a [limited way](https://support.gupshup.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012075759-What-is-Sandbox-app-and-how-does-it-work-), unlike a live app where you are able to send a template message (BIC) to opt-in users even if they are inactive.

If your app is in a sandbox - the destination number should be marked as opt-in and active(this can be done by interacting with your app via proxy number: https://wa.me/917834811114). Also, you will not be able to submit a new template to WhatsApp for review/approval till your app is live.